# Removing all characters after Special Character in Column Name

Tags: r, rename, special-characters

I have a data set that I have imported into R, but need to get rid of everything in the column names after "(".  I've tried `string.split(), sub(), and grepl()` functions, but no success.  Any and all help would be appreciated!

I would like the following to become this:

> > Fruit              =>   Fruit
> >
> > Vegetables (Few)   =>   Vegetable
> >
> > Bread Crumbs       =>   Bread Crumbs
> >
> > Cheese (Cheddar)   =>   Cheese
> >
> > Yogurt (Plain%)    =>   Yogurt

Comment: Try `sub("\\s*\\(.*$", "", v1)`

Comment: To demonstrate @akrun answer, try: `v1 <- colnames(your_df); colnames(your_df) <- sub("\\s*\\(.*$", "", v1)` It's a regular expression that removes anything that occurs after a space `\\s` followed by an open parenthesis `\\(`.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
items <- c('Fruit', 'Vegetables (Few)', 'Bread Crumbs', 'Cheese (Cheddar)', 'Yogurt (Plain%)')
items_simplified <- trimws(gsub('\\(.*', '', items))

> items_simplified
[1] "Fruit"        "Vegetables"   "Bread Crumbs" "Cheese"       "Yogurt"
```

You could also use `stringr` from the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(stringr)
items_stringr <- str_trim(str_extract(items, '[^(]*'))

> items_stringr
[1] "Fruit"        "Vegetables"   "Bread Crumbs" "Cheese"       "Yogurt"
```

`trimws` and `str_trim` trim the trailing and leading whitespace from the items.

Answer (score -1):

Use regex or regular expression

Like: /(.+)/g

And remove everything that is found

Comment: `.+` would just select all characters, and you don't have any code associated with the regex